# convert a list with lists to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, lapply, rvest

A website contains some reviews of books, which I would like to scrape with rvest. It's possible to get the data like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

result_list <-
  lapply(1:2, function(i) {
    url <- paste0("http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/buchkritik.949.de.html?drbm:page=",         i)
    parse_url <- 
      url %>%
      xml2::read_html()
    parse_page <-
      list(page = parse_url %>% html_nodes("span.drk-paginationanzahl") %>% html_text(),
           date = parse_url %>% html_nodes(".drk-container") %>% html_nodes(".drk-sendungdatum") %>% html_text(),
           text = parse_url %>% html_nodes(".drk-container") %>% html_nodes(".drk-overline") %>% html_text(),
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
      rbind()
  })
```

The length of "date" differ sometimes with "text", so I used list. Now I struggle to convert the list into a dataframe. Do you have some hints for me to converting the list? Maybe there is a more elegant way for webscrape to avoid these... The dataframe should have the columns "page", "date" and "text". (in a next step I split the content of text in author and title)

I tried the approaches:

```
result_df1 <-
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, result_list))

result_df2 <-
  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(result_list, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))

result_df3 <-
  as.data.frame(Reduce( rbind, lapply(result_list, unlist) ))

result_df4 <-
  as.data.frame(lapply(result_list, unlist))

result_df5 <-
  lapply(result_list, tidyr::unnest)

result_df6 <-
  result_list %>% purrr::dmap(unlist)

result_df7 <-
  result_list %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>%
  tibble::enframe() %>%
  unnest()
```

In result_df1 and  result_df2, the dataframe has a list in each cell. How it is possible to unlist these by column?
I think a big problem is that the length differed per list element. How can I handle this?

Example1 is similar to my problem with different length in the list. With equal length (example2) I struggle with a convertion to a dataframe too.

```
example1 <- 
  list(structure(list("page 1/490",
                      c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                      c("author1: \"title1\"", "author2: \"title2\"", "author3: \"title3\"", "author4: \"title4\""), 
                      FALSE),   
                 .Dim = c(1L, 4L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(".", c("page", "date", "text", "stringsAsFactors"))), 
       structure(list("page 2/490", 
                      c("e", "f", "g"), 
                      c("author5: \"title5\"", "author6: \"title6\"", "author7: \"title7\"", "author8: \"title8\""),
                      FALSE),   
                 .Dim = c(1L, 4L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(".", c("page", "date", "text", "stringsAsFactors")))

)


example2 <- 
  list(structure(list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
                      c("author1: \"title1\"", "author2: \"title2\"", "author3: \"title3\"", "author4: \"title4\""), 
                      FALSE),   
                 .Dim = c(1L, 3L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(".", c("date", "text", "stringsAsFactors"))), 
       structure(list(c("e", "f", "g", "h"), 
                      c("author5: \"title5\"", "author6: \"title6\"", "author7: \"title7\"", "author8: \"title8\""),
                      FALSE),   
                 .Dim = c(1L, 3L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(".", c("date", "text", "stringsAsFactors")))

  )
```

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (ideally one that doesn't involved web scraping) and provide the desired output to make it more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: On the second page, one of the `.drk-sendungdatum` elements is just not on the page. Because there's no enclosing tags for each set, it's a bit of a pain to figure out where the `NA` needs to go.

Comment: As alistaire notes there seem to be structural problem with the pages. I tried looking at it  but could not find a consistent way. Did you notice they publish RSS links? (look at the bottom  of the web page) this may give you a more consistent XML to process,

Comment: @MrFlick I have added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the second page, one of the `.drk-sendungdatum` items is missing from its corresponding item, so there are an uneven number of elements so a data.frame can't be constructed. Because there are no enclosing tags, it is hard to figure out where an `NA` should go, but it is relatively easy to subset out the extra `.drk-overline` item by looking for a `span` immediately before (`+`) the enclosing `article` tag:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

pages <- 1:2 %>% 
    paste0("http://www.deutschlandradiokultur.de/buchkritik.949.de.html?drbm:page=", .) %>% 
    map(read_html)

result_list <- pages %>% 
    map(html_nodes, '.drk-container') %>%
    map_df(~data_frame(page = .x %>% html_node("span.drk-paginationanzahl") %>% html_text(),
                       date = .x %>% html_nodes(".drk-sendungdatum") %>% html_text(),
                       text = .x %>% html_nodes("span + article .drk-overline") %>% html_text()))
```

If you really want, you can reparse `pages` to add the problematic observation, though it takes a little work:

```r
result_list <- pages %>% 
    map_df(~list(page = .x %>% html_node('span.drk-paginationanzahl') %>% html_text(), 
                 date = NA, 
                 text = .x %>% html_node('.drk-container :not(span) + article .drk-overline') %>% html_text())) %>% 
    drop_na(text) %>% 
    bind_rows(result_list)
```

Now note the `NA` value of `date` at the top:

```r
result_list
#> # A tibble: 50 × 3
#>           page                   date
#>          <chr>                  <chr>
#> 1  Seite 2/490                   <NA>
#> 2  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 24.04.2017
#> 3  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 21.04.2017
#> 4  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 20.04.2017
#> 5  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 19.04.2017
#> 6  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 18.04.2017
#> 7  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 15.04.2017
#> 8  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 13.04.2017
#> 9  Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 12.04.2017
#> 10 Seite 1/490 Sendung vom 11.04.2017
#> # ... with 40 more rows, and 1 more variables: text <chr>
```

Comment: Great. That works. The solution with map was new for me.